# Install4j 6 example: Collect form data and create properties file

Tags: install4j

Is there an Install4J 6 example project how to collect data via a form (e.g. host, port, database) and create a properties file from the collected data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there should be such a sample. I've added one for 6.0.2. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build, I'd be grateful for your feedback.